# Streamed output from a WCF service

Tags: wcf, streaming

I am trying to get streamed output from a WCF service.

I have set the `transferMode` to "`StreamedResponse`". When client receives the stream from server, it is unable to read the stream. While debugging from server side I can see that the stream has data, but from client side stream.Length throws a NotSupportedException. Reading the stream into a buffer results in 0 bytes read.

I generated the client proxy using svcutil, and am using .NET 3.0. Has anyone experienced a similar problem?

Comment: The link in your comment is not working http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2008/06/10/streaming-large-content-with-wcf-and-deferred-execution.aspx.....except

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to help without any details, but note that VS2005 Cassini server (asp.net development server) doesn't support streaming over http.

Comment: I am trying to serialize a list of objects and send them to client side via a stream.

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();            
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(ms, GetAllCustomers());
            return ms;

Comment: However when I read a simple text file into a filestream, I can read it at client side.

Comment: Do you enforce binary encoding?

<customBinding>   
  <binding name="streamingBinding">      
    <binaryMessageEncoding />
    <tcpTransport transferMode=”Streamed” />   
  </binding>
</customBinding>

Comment: I ended up using streaming in a different way....I used this example and it worked for me....http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2008/06/10/streaming-large-content-with-wcf-and-deferred-execution.aspx.....except that setting parameters is hard

Comment: the above link is not working http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2008/06/10/streaming-large-content-with-wcf-and-deferred-execution.aspx.....except

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2008/06/10/streaming-large-content-with-wcf-and-deferred-execution.aspx